# Missing dynamic transform snapping in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms, snapping

I have downloaded the Blender 2.8 Alpha2 from the 21 September 2018.

There I tried to snap my object to the current visible grid.
This was supported in 2.79. Also the documentation of 2.79
confirms the behaviour.

[image: Blender snapping documentation 2.79]

*All the GIFS were made with factory settings. I hold CTRL for snapping while moving the Object. I made no changes to the settings or else.*

So this is how it looks in 2.79
[image]

And this is 2.80 alpha 2
[image]

So, does anyone know if this will be part of 2.80 later?
Or is this change intentional?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a version of Blender still in development.

Comment: I agree that this behaviour is not guaranteed to stay until the final release and so this question may become off-topic. @Karotte, you could try submitting an idea to https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ since, if I'm not mistaken, the bug tracker is not currently accepting 2.8's bugs except for crashes.

Comment: Thx for the advice. I hoped that there is may a new option which i overlooked ;)

Comment: The blender developers are [currently working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrL0tbBTKus&lc=Ugx_OnA7g5HCRaKX_KZ4AaABAg.8lwiUwNG3C78lwwbHFyXUd) on it

Answer (score 2):

**Update 3 Oct 2018**: the behaviour is going to change

> «Yes! This has been reported and it will be worked on soon»
>
> — *Pablo Vazquez* (a Blender developer) [in the comments to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrL0tbBTKus&lc=Ugx_OnA7g5HCRaKX_KZ4AaABAg.8lwiUwNG3C78lwwbHFyXUd)

---

Well, technically also in 2.8 the snap uses the grid being displayed. It's just that the grid no longer changes its refinement when changing zoom level: the smaller grid lines only get dimmer and dimmer but are still there.

[image]

<sup>*(no matter how much I zoom out, there is always a grid refinement level as fine as my cubes)*</sup>

Anyway, I agree with you that when the "centimeters" have gotten too dim to be useful to all intent and purposes, the "decimeters" should become the "main" snapping increment and so on.